# Store appsettings.json in Azure App Service Web App

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service

I have created my first ASP Core MVC 3.1 app and published it in Azure. This works fine but I noticed that my settings.json file is visible in the root exposing my db connection string and Azure AD info.

I have been successful in 'hiding' the db connection string by adding a new connection string called Database in App Service>Settings>configuration. I named it the same as the entry in my settings.json file and it magically works. I have now removed this from the settings.json file.

In Startup I use

```
 var connection = Configuration.GetConnectionString("Database");
        services.AddDbContext<BookStoreContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connection));
```

The Azure login info is in an Array so I am not sure how I add this to the App Service Settings:

```
"AzureAd": {
"Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
"Domain": "xxxx.onmicrosoft.com",
"TenantId": "xxxxxx-a2dd-4fde-bf8f-f75ab18b21ac",
"ClientId": "xxxxxxxxx-a9bb-4722-b615-6dcbdc646326",
"ClientSecret":xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
"CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc"
```

},

In Startup I use:

```
services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddAzureAD(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));
```

Any help will be much appeciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Do yiu have any update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my test, if you want to store array settings in Azure App Service configuration. You have two choices.

With Azure APP service window, you can store it like {"AzureAd:Domain" :""}

[image]

[image]

With App Service on Linux or Web App for Containers, you can store it like {"AzureAd_Domain" :""}

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

> The Azure login info is in an Array so I am not sure how I add this to the App Service Settings

You can try to add these setting data with nested JSON key structure as below in Application settings.

[image]

For more information about setting configuration keys and values, please check these Docs:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#configuration-keys-and-values
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-common#add-or-edit